# Trying to build dependency trees from npm packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am currently working on a research project where I'd like to compare dependency trees for repositories hosted on GitHub, but which depend on packages published on npm. Please note that I am no expert in Node/npm so I may be doing things/assuming wrong and would be happy to hear about it too!

So basically, I git clone several repos from Github. Some of those have a `package.json` file, others have a `package-lock.json` file.

My initial thought to get that dependency tree was to do the following:

- `cd` into local folder
- `npm install`
- `npm list --all > tree.txt` or something like that, formatted as json

For some repos, it works well and I have a dependency tree that has no errors. For others however, I have a tree, but which will include some error about invalid dependencies. Most of the time, it has to do with `react` or `typescript` versions that are required by different dependencies, and which require different major versions. So the first one in line would download version `1.3.2` for example, then another dependency down the tree would require version `^2.3.1`, which leads to a fail because there is already another version installed. I have tried to install with `--force`, or to do `npm update` then `npm install`, to no avail.

My question is the following. How can I generate a valid dependency tree for those types of packages? do I need to manually edit `package.json` files on my cloned repo to change version numbers and retry `npm install`? If so, what would be the way to go about it that would represent how devs typically do this in this scenario?

To be clear my goal is not to run that project, it's really to get a sense of the dependencies required by that package.

The alternative I have identified, otherwise, is to query, for each dependency, the npm registry to retrieve a valid version of a required package, then retrieve its dependencies and so on until I manually rebuild the tree. Not ideal, but doable, and would generate a "theoretical" list of npm dependencies for a given repo I guess. The other thing is that it would mean quite a few calls to the registry, something I was hoping to avoid. Not sure if there are quotas or something in place to do that but I would write something sensible with `sleep` between calls.

Thank you for your insights, and happy to provide more details if needed.

Cheers!

P.S: I cannot use `npm-remote-ls` because the project where I want to generate the tree is not hosted on npm, it's just a GitHub repo.